# Installing important updates for Windows Update

Tags: c#, windows, windows-update, wuapi

```
// Create installer from list
IUpdateInstaller installer = session.CreateUpdateInstaller();
installer.Updates = updatesToInstall;

// Install updates
IInstallationResult installationRes = installer.Install();
```

I can make optional updates using this. But important updates are "failing". Could you help?

Comment: Please elaborate on *but important updates are "failing"*.

Comment: in return `installationRes.ResultCode = orcFailed`

Comment: You should try to read the HRESULT value from the `installationRes` reference, which would further give you the idea what went wrong!

Comment: I could not understand, would you open a little more

Comment: I meant along with reading `installationRes.ResultCode` you should also read `installationRes.HResult` value which **Gets the HRESULT of the exception, if any, that is raised during the installation**. Once you know the error code, you'd get to know what resulted to the failure of patch installation.

Comment: I understand, I will try

Comment: When I do Microsoft Word update, `installationRes.HResult` value is "-2145124318". Not updating

Comment: The error "-2145124318" means `Operation failed for all the updates.Source: Windows Update Agent`. Would you be able to check the Windows Update log file of the system where you're trying to install the update? It might have a better description of what actually is happening.

Comment: I examined; "Installation Error: Windows could not install the update with the **0x80070663 error**: Security Update for Microsoft Word 2016 (KB4022218) 64-Bit Version."

Comment: Check this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e3e5321c-265a-42a0-a218-d666c8c7e7f3/office-updates-fail-with-error-0x80070663?forum=Office2016ITPro, and check if non-office updates are installing successfully or not.

Comment: Thank you for your last responsibility. My pc is Windows 7. Does it work on other Windows 10 and 8?

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to suggest that! But, as I said, please try downloading and installing other types/categories of updates for other products(OS / IE / .NET, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your help